# Text slider increases offset from the left after each iteration

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am basically transferring existing slider from existing site to a new one, and I didn't want to waste additional time by figuring out how to create a text slider from scratch, since the client wants the same thing on his new site.

I found the code and modified it a bit to work on the new site. Except it doesn't really works as it should. The slider looks like this:

```js
var counter = 1;
var total_width = 0;

function slider_total_width() {
  $('.items a').each(function() {
    total_width += parseInt($(this).width(), 10);
  });

  $('.items').width(total_width);
}

slider_total_width();

function job_slider(wrapper) {
  var first_link = $('#active');
  var width = first_link.width();
  $(wrapper + ' a').each(function() {
    total_width += $(this).width() + 50;
  });
  first_link.removeAttr('id');
  $(wrapper).animate({
    left: '-=' + width
  }, 1000, function() {
    $(first_link).clone().appendTo(wrapper);
    $(first_link).css('color', 'transparent');
    var links = $(wrapper + ' a');
    var new_first_link = links[counter];
    counter++;
    $(new_first_link).attr('id', 'active');
    $(wrapper).width(total_width);
    total_width = 0;
  });
}

var activate = function() {
  job_slider('.items');
};
var interval = setInterval(activate, 5000);

$('.items').hover(function() {
  clearInterval(interval);
}, function() {
  interval = setInterval(activate, 5000);
});
```

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 700px;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
#ads_scroller .container {
  font-size: 0;
  position: relative;
}
#ads_scroller .icon_holder {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 3%;
  margin-top: 8px;
}
#ads_scroller .icon_holder i {
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #fe9700;
}
#ads_scroller .scroller_container {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 97%;
  height: 31px;
  position: relative;
}
#ads_scroller .scroller_container .items {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
#ads_scroller .scrollable_title {
  position: relative;
  color: #727272;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 41px;
  display: inline;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 0 0 0 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#ads_scroller .scrollable_title:last-of-type {
  margin-right: 0;
}
#ads_scroller #active.scrollable_title {
  color: #1a171b;
}
#ads_scroller .scrollable_title:hover {
  color: #555;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div id="ads_scroller">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="icon_holder"><i class="fa fa-bell-o"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="scroller_container">
      <div class="items" style="width: 2642px;">
        <a href="#" class="scrollable_title" id="active">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet  – </a>
        <a href="#" class="scrollable_title">Consectetur adipisicing elit – </a>
        <a href="#" class="scrollable_title">Incidunt tempore explicabo ea autem, eligendi excepturi – </a>
        <a href="#" class="scrollable_title">Sapiente sint officiis non minima ex – </a>
        <a href="#" class="scrollable_title">Tenetur provident, ipsum dignissimos autem earum nobis dolor – </a>
        <a href="#" class="scrollable_title">Obcaecati iste animi cumque culpa – </a>
        <a href="#" class="scrollable_title">Vero asperiores illum rerum – </a>
        <a href="#" class="scrollable_title">Test to see how announcements look – </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now I think I know what the issue is, but I don't know how to fix it. For some reason, my `.items` wrapper, if it doesn't have set width, won't have all the links in one line, so after a while I won't have any links inside to scroll.

Strangely this isn't set on the client side and I couldn't figure out what css rule they used that will allow this (move to left infinitely without width being set). So to circumvent this I'm calculating total width, and then setting it each time the slider clones the element that passed.

But what this does (at least that's my guess) is that after a while the gap between the `.items` wrapper start on the left (where the icon is), and the link that slides in, becomes progressively bigger. After a minute or so the gap becomes really big.

So is there a way to prevent this? What am I doing wrong here? :\

Answer (score 1):

Hi try this sample i hope it help you

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Demo Slider</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
    <div  class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="item active" >
            <div class="caption">
              <a href="#" class="scrollable_title" id="active">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet  – </a>
        <a href="#" class="scrollable_title">Consectetur adipisicing elit – </a>
        <a href="#" class="scrollable_title">Incidunt tempore explicabo ea autem, eligendi excepturi – </a>
        <a href="#" class="scrollable_title">Sapiente sint officiis non minima ex – </a>
        <a href="#" class="scrollable_title">Tenetur provident, ipsum dignissimos autem earum nobis dolor – </a>
        <a href="#" class="scrollable_title">Obcaecati iste animi cumque culpa – </a>
        <a href="#" class="scrollable_title">Vero asperiores illum rerum – </a>
        <a href="#" class="scrollable_title">Test to see how announcements look – </a>

            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="item " >
            <div class="caption">
              <a href="#" class="scrollable_title" id="active">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet  – </a>
        <a href="#" class="scrollable_title">Consectetur adipisicing elit – </a>
        <a href="#" class="scrollable_title">Incidunt tempore explicabo ea autem, eligendi excepturi – </a>
        <a href="#" class="scrollable_title">Sapiente sint officiis non minima ex – </a>
        <a href="#" class="scrollable_title">Tenetur provident, ipsum dignissimos autem earum nobis dolor – </a>
        <a href="#" class="scrollable_title">Obcaecati iste animi cumque culpa – </a>
        <a href="#" class="scrollable_title">Vero asperiores illum rerum – </a>
        <a href="#" class="scrollable_title">Test to see how announcements look – </a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="item" >
            <div class="caption">
              <a href="#" class="scrollable_title" id="active">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet  – </a>
        <a href="#" class="scrollable_title">Consectetur adipisicing elit – </a>
        <a href="#" class="scrollable_title">Incidunt tempore explicabo ea autem, eligendi excepturi – </a>
        <a href="#" class="scrollable_title">Sapiente sint officiis non minima ex – </a>
        <a href="#" class="scrollable_title">Tenetur provident, ipsum dignissimos autem earum nobis dolor – </a>
        <a href="#" class="scrollable_title">Obcaecati iste animi cumque culpa – </a>
        <a href="#" class="scrollable_title">Vero asperiores illum rerum – </a>
        <a href="#" class="scrollable_title">Test to see how announcements look – </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>


      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you add a working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) to show how your above code works?

Comment: I'm trying not to include bootstrap in my project, plus the carousel needs to be going item by item.

Answer (score 0):

You can try outerwidth() instead of width() as I think the solution is to add +2px to the width which is actually the padding-left of each anchor item.

```js
var counter = 1;
var total_width = 0;

function slider_total_width() {
  $('.items a').each(function() {
    total_width += parseInt($(this).outerWidth(), 10);
  });

  $('.items').width(total_width);
}

slider_total_width();

function job_slider(wrapper) {
  var first_link = $('#active');
  var width = first_link.outerWidth();
  $(wrapper + ' a').each(function() {
    total_width += $(this).width() + 50;
  });
  first_link.removeAttr('id');
  $(wrapper).animate({
    left: '-=' + width
  }, 1000, function() {
    $(first_link).clone().appendTo(wrapper);
    $(first_link).css('color', 'transparent');
    var links = $(wrapper + ' a');
    var new_first_link = links[counter];
    counter++;
    $(new_first_link).attr('id', 'active');
    $(wrapper).width(total_width);
    total_width = 0;
  });
}

var activate = function() {
  job_slider('.items');
};
var interval = setInterval(activate, 5000);

$('.items').hover(function() {
  clearInterval(interval);
}, function() {
  interval = setInterval(activate, 5000);
});
```

```css
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 700px;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
#ads_scroller .container {
  font-size: 0;
  position: relative;
}
#ads_scroller .icon_holder {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 3%;
  margin-top: 8px;
}
#ads_scroller .icon_holder i {
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #fe9700;
}
#ads_scroller .scroller_container {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 97%;
  height: 31px;
  position: relative;
}
#ads_scroller .scroller_container .items {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
#ads_scroller .scrollable_title {
  position: relative;
  color: #727272;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 41px;
  display: inline;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 0 0 0 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#ads_scroller .scrollable_title:last-of-type {
  margin-right: 0;
}
#ads_scroller #active.scrollable_title {
  color: #1a171b;
}
#ads_scroller .scrollable_title:hover {
  color: #555;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div id="ads_scroller">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="icon_holder"><i class="fa fa-bell-o"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="scroller_container">
      <div class="items" style="width: 2642px;">
        <a href="#" class="scrollable_title" id="active">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet  – </a>
        <a href="#" class="scrollable_title">Consectetur adipisicing elit – </a>
        <a href="#" class="scrollable_title">Incidunt tempore explicabo ea autem, eligendi excepturi – </a>
        <a href="#" class="scrollable_title">Sapiente sint officiis non minima ex – </a>
        <a href="#" class="scrollable_title">Tenetur provident, ipsum dignissimos autem earum nobis dolor – </a>
        <a href="#" class="scrollable_title">Obcaecati iste animi cumque culpa – </a>
        <a href="#" class="scrollable_title">Vero asperiores illum rerum – </a>
        <a href="#" class="scrollable_title">Test to see how announcements look – </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tried setting that, but didn't help :\

Comment: Edited the answer to show that the code works. Please mark it answer if it worked for you already.